# A Riddle of Mine

Tags: word, wordplay, english

I came up with this riddle a few years ago, and so far very few people have been able to solve it:

Think of a four-letter word (“_ _ _ _”) such that adding an A to the beginning (“a _ _ _ _”) changes the meaning *but not the pronunciation*. (It's a normal word that I guarantee anyone with at least a middle-school education will have heard.)

If you answer, **please use spoiler tags.**

Comment: Wow, this is a good first riddle. I'm gonna be racking my brains over this one.

Comment: After thinking for some time, I got the solution that is mentioned in the first answer https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/75380/44626 . I do not know whether a redundant answer is OK, so I just wrote this comment.

Answer (score 38):

I'll go with

> **isle** - an island - which is pronounced the same as **aisle** - a walkway.

Comment: This depends on accent a fair bit. Around here, your first answer is pronounced as one syllable while your second is distinctly two.

Comment: Any fan of Piers Anthony's *Xanth* books should have gotten this very quickly.

Comment: I didn't even know this word, and I have a Proficiency in English.

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps another couple of solutions are

> Iran, which when you add an "a" becomes airan, which, according to Webster's Third New International unabridged, is pronounced the same as one possible pronunciation of Iran, but means a Turkish drink made from fermented milk

And

> Erie (the city) and aerie which can also be pronounced the same, but means a nest.

However, these are

> capitalized words, so perhaps they don't quite fit. And though middle school students probably know Erie and Iran, and maybe even aerie, it is doubtful they know airan.

Comment: I'd argue that a "middle-school student" knows of either

Comment: Iran and ayran are pronounced differently (*ihr-ahn* vs *aye-rahn*). Also, it's a**y**ran, not airan.

Comment: @Randal'Thor: Please don't quote solutions in comments without obfuscating them.   :-)   ⁠

Comment: @Randal'Thor It [can be spelled with i](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/airan), but I agree the pronunciation is different. For one, the milk product has stress on the first syllable, the country on the last.

Answer (score 4):

Probably not this, but worth writing down:

> Aron and Aaron are names, referring to different people but pronounced the same.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with Tom's answer, but would like to mention another possibility, which is

> Ide - a [freshwater fish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ide_(fish)).

Which of course yields

> Aide

As the other word. Neither is one that would necessarily be known by everyone though.

Comment: Your word is only three letters instead of four.

Comment: @ralphmerridew dammit can't imagine how I made that mistake. You can of course use plural to make it four letters but that would be an even bigger stretch

Comment: (1) I don't recall ever hearing of your three-letter word, and I'm a college graduate with a fairly large vocabulary. The question says "anyone with at least a middle-school education will have heard" of these words.  (2) Also, do you claim that your two words are pronounced the same, as required by the question? None of the resources I found indicated that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this wasn't covered yet:

> long (/lôNG,läNG/): distance/lasting.
>  along (/əˈlôNG,əˈläNG/): together/accompany.

and

> rose (/rōz/): flower.
>  arose (/əˈrōz/): emerge.

Updated:

> [iris](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/iris) [aɪrɪs]: the round coloured part that surrounds the pupil of your eye.
>  [airis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/airis) [āīɾis]: oar, paddle (an instrument for rowing a boat).

Comment: I believe the condition that the pronunciation doesn't change after prepending *a* applies to the whole words ("????" and "A????"), not just the last four letters.

Comment: I might've misinterpreted it then since it wasn't implicitly stated the "whole words" but "changes the meaning but not the pronunciation". So I assume it was only the original four letter.

Answer (score 0):

What about

> rise
>  arise

... must have 30 chars.

Comment: I don't think this works because of the condition: "adding an A to the beginning changes the meaning **but not the pronunciation**".

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE!

Comment: Ah nevermind, I misread that part.

Answer (score 0):

> aaah $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: But it doesn't change the meaning!